# How do I fix two finger scroll on the Lenovo X1 Carbon (3rd Gen) touchpad?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, laptop, thinkpad, synaptics

The touchpad on the Lenovo X1 Carbon (3rd Gen) is supposed to support two-finger scroll. However even after enabling it the two-finger scroll support is broken and using two fingers has no additional effect.

Answer (score 0):

After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the correct driver for the touchpad is not installed out of the box. To fix this run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04` in a terminal and restart your computer.